# Get info from JSON data and store into CSV file

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, csv, numpy

I am able to get Name,Info and Points( all the data present inside this is coming in as whole data).
Here is the sample input data:

```
data : [[{'Info':'http:\/\/www.epa.gov\/enviro\/geo_data.html', 'Name':'US RCRA Generators (CESQG, SQG, LQG)', 'Color':[
240, 180, 120 ], 'Points':[
{
'Direction':'1.64069406001901', 'Description':'SRID=4326;POINT(-111.74632     33.29791)', 'Fields':[
{
'Value':'COSTCO #644', 'Key':'Primary Name' }, {
'Value':'2887 S MARKET ST', 'Key':'Address' }, {
'Value':'GILBERT', 'Key':'City' }, {
'Value':'MARICOPA', 'Key':'County' }, {
'Value':'ONE-HOUR PHOTOFINISHING., OTHER GASOLINE STATIONS.', 'Key':'NAICS     Descriptions' } ], 'Longitude':'-111.74632', 'Latitude':'33.29791',     'Type':'ST_Point' } ]]]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
info_list = []
name_list = []
points_list = []
lat_list = []
long_list = []
for ff in finalJson:
    for gg in ff:
        info = gg['Info']
        name = gg['Name']
        points = gg['Points']
        info_list.append(info)
        name_list.append(name)
        points_list.append(points)
```

But need to get the key value data in the csv(quoted things as column name and values as rows with their respective) :  'Name','Info','Points'['Latitude'],'Points'['Longitude'],'Points'['Fields'[all the key,values of this inside block]]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)?

It does a pretty good job of flattening the object into a pandas dataframe:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(json_data['data'])
print(df.head())
```

Then clean/restructure the dataframe, at last export it to CSV using [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
df.to_csv('/path/output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Edit:** Splitting 'Points' column into multiple columns.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Info').Points.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index()
final_df = pd.concat([df, df2])
print(final_df)
```

Comment: Your approach is correct but the data is like list of dictionary, because of this I'm getting 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'. Any modifications needs to be added to solve this?